# how to use JQuery for a tag that create in PHP if condition

Tags: php, jquery

how to use JQuery for a tag that create in PHP if condition.
suppose i like to show a p tag when an if condition results true by fadeIn function animation.
could u please make an example for me??
thanks a lot

Comment: You output the `<p>` tag and define a `display: none` inside your style sheets for that element. Then you can select it by means of jquery on the client side and use the `fadeIn()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
<?php

if(condition == true) {

?>
<script>
$("#yourElement").show();
</script>

<?php
} else {
?>
<script>
$("#yourElement").hide();
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```